# Android where save the server configuration and be able to update it

Tags: android, configuration, apk

I have developped an Android application using web service and JBoss.
Now i have to install my application on the customer's servers. Then each customer have a different ip/url for the server.

i want to create a configuration file next to my file .apk. How i can do that ? I need the posibility to modify the file to not re-compile my application for each customer.

Thanks for your response ;-)

Comment: To avoid multiple URL/IP, Can you host it in a single server and ask the customers to connect via username-password credentials?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because my application is for some companies. And each company have some final customers. Then each company have his own server. Thanks for your response :-)